# jQuery Load doesn't works - Page Not Found 404

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is like 8 hours into this that I'm trying to fix it.
This might be a petty issue, but I'm not sure why in the world it isn't working.

I'm trying to **refresh a div** with **jQuery.Load** but it throws a weird 404 error. The page does exist and I'm not sure why it ain't taking it.

It was working well before when I hadn't added wordpress header files. Once I added them, it went haywire.

Here's my code

```
$( "#feed" ).load(window.location.href + " #feed" );
```

I've also tried this :-

```
$( "#tab1" ).load("http://example.com/community.php?#tab1" );
```

The JS code is written on the same file `community.php`

Here's the error :-

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   community.php:1
```

Comment: Ah just wrote it wrong here. I actually tried the correct URL.

Comment: In the browser console, if you copy the network request and paste it in the browser I assume you also get a 404?

Comment: Will it work without `#fragment`? Isn't that client-side only? (Just a guess.)

Comment: Just use `$( "#tab1" ).load("./community.php?#tab1" );` no need for full url.

Comment: Can we see some the HTML of the page you are loading?  You are trying to load a fragment yes? The `id` is unique and you are not mixing up this concept with href #anchors?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone
This is what I get
`GET http:// domain.com/community.php? 404 (Not Found)       jquery.min.js:2 `

Comment: @ficuscr
Correct. So I have a feed of posts which Im trying to refresh. The container div has  id `feed` and this id isn;t used anywhere. There's a class with this name but no id.

Answer (score 0):

All the examples I see have a space between the selector and the URL. Like so:

```
$("#tab1").load("http://example.com/community.php? #tab1");
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/load/ - "Loading Page Fragments"

Also, it seems problematic to load a fragment into a div that has the same `id`. If the space does not resolve the issue, try removing the `#tab1` id from the page?

```
$("#tab1_target").load("http://example.com/community.php #tab1");
```

Also just noticing that `?`... which seems odd as you are not passing any GET parameters. Not sure how well you copied your actual code into the question so this might all be moot.